# How can I use libsvm on scikit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to use libsvm as a classifier for predicition. I have used the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn.svm import libsvm

X = np.array([[0,1.22,45,2.111,9.344,0], [0,1.5,25,5,1,0]])
y = np.array([0.0,1.0])

clf=sklearn.svm.libsvm

clf.fit(X,y)

print(clf.predict([1,1.12,42,4.223,2.33,0]))
```

I got following error:
 File "sklearn/svm/libsvm.pyx", line 270, in sklearn.svm.libsvm.predict (sklearn/svm/libsvm.c:3917)
TypeError: predict() takes at least 6 positional arguments (1 given)

Is this the correct way? How can I resolve the error?

Comment: Check out the excellent docs. You are doing a wrong import (don't use the low-level stuff). It's called [sklearn.svm.SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html). Apart from that, your python-usage in regards to calling your imported function is wrong too, so one more documentation (python) you should consider.

Answer (score 0):

Basically use sklearn.svm.SVC, since as it is stated in the documentation of sklearn, SVC is based on libsvm:

```
class SVC(BaseSVC):
   C-Support Vector Classification.
```

> The implementation is based on libsvm. The fit time complexity
>       is more than quadratic with the number of samples which makes it hard
>       to scale to dataset with more than a couple of 10000 samples.